# How to connect SQL Server 2008 R2 from linux machine in QT[C++]?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect SQL Server R2 which on windows machine, from my Linux machine. I unable to connect SQL Server.

My code for connecting database which is not work for me:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include<QtSql>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");
   db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=192.162.1.108;Database=WIN-UK71JUGMM8T;Uid=sa;Port=1433;Pwd=sa@123;WSID=.");
   db.open();
   if(!db.open())
    {
        qDebug()<<"ERRORR MESSAGE: =>" << db.lastError().text();
        return 0;
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

It give me following error:

```
ERRORR MESSAGE: => "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect"
```

My .pro file:

```
QT       += core sql
QT       -= gui
TARGET   = SQLTest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE  = app
SOURCES  += main.cpp
```

Please tell me if want to make some procedure on WINDOWS machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine for the most part. It's the same as what I have for my own SQL Server client application. But there may be some errors :

**Edit :** You mixed up the IP and Database name. Your host is "WIN-UK71JUGMM8T" as your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qXHp.png) showed me. The "Database" field corresponds to the database you want ot open in the "Database" subfolder.

**Host :**

```
WIN-UK71JUGMM8T\SQLEXPRESS
```

**Connection String**

```
db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=WIN-UK71JUGMM8T\SQLEXPRESS;Database='Your DB Name';Uid=sa;Port=1433;Pwd=sa@123;WSID=.");
```

For the driver, you should use `QODBC` instead of `QODBC3`. Qt is supposed to pick the right one, and you shouldn't have to specify the version number.

Other error is your `db.open()`, you only need it in the `if` statement

```
db.open(); //Remove this line, as you call it in your if statement
if(!db.open())
{
    qDebug()<<"ERRORR MESSAGE: =>" << db.lastError().text();
    return 0;
}
```

A good practice is also to list the available drivers by using :

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
qDebug() << db.drivers();
```

Comment: Thank yo sir, please check my changes

Comment: After make your changes it give same error as followes:
`DRIVERS =>  ("QIBASE", "QSQLITE", "QSQLITE3", "QMYSQL3", "QMYSQL", "QODBC3", "QODBC", "QPSQL7", "QPSQL", "QTDS7", "QTDS") 


ERRORR MESSAGE: => "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect"`
Is there any need to install some driver on my linux machine? for connecting them or any configuration changes?. Beauce i can connect in JAVA but not in QT c++

Comment: By "driver", Qt means his own dlls (found in the Qt installation folder), in the sqldrivers folder, or libs if you run on Linux. They are specific to Qt, and do not need to be separately installed. Try by removing the port, as the [documentation](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/)  doesn't specify it

Comment: I found answer. i change `QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC"); ` to `QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QTDS");` and it work for me